# how toshow alert in SwiftUI that Email and Password are incorrect?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, game-development

Good Evening,

I have a question, I need to show an error when a user enters a wrong email or enters a wrong password. What do I need to add in my code?
I am new to software development and Sam not so familiar with swift ui could someone help me?

```
    @State var email = ""
    @State var password = ""



    var body: some View {
        Image("ISD-Logo")
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
            .frame(width: 185, height: 140)
            .clipped()
            .padding(.bottom, 75)
        
        VStack {
            TextField("Email", text: $email)
                .padding()
                .background(Color(UIColor.lightGray))
                .cornerRadius(5.0)
                .padding(.bottom, 20)
            SecureField("password", text: $password)
                .padding()
                .background(Color(UIColor.lightGray))
                .cornerRadius(5.0)
                .padding(.bottom, 20)
            Button(action: { login() }) {
                Text("Sign in")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding()
                    .frame(width: 220, height: 60)
                    .background(Color.black)
                    .cornerRadius(35.0)
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
    

    //    Login and error message
    func login() {
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
            } else {
                print("success")
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
struct LoginView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LoginView()
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? What research have you done? What part of your code isn't working? With a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) we can help you work out the kinks but SO is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of alert do you want?

You can do that:

```js
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showingAlert = false

    var body: some View {
        Button("Show Alert") {
            showingAlert = true
        }
        .alert("Important message", isPresented: $showingAlert) {
            Button("OK", role: .cancel) { }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The login() function, if it returns immediately, could return a value which is then used to either set the showingAlert to true, or else to show whatever comes next after logging in.  Note, though, that if the login happens over the internet, it should happen asynchronously so that you aren't locking up the main thread while the login happens. How to handle that is well beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this. I would suggest you go to ***SWIFT UI*** basics first

```
@State var email = ""
    @State var password = ""



    var body: some View {
        Image("ISD-Logo")
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
            .frame(width: 185, height: 140)
            .clipped()
            .padding(.bottom, 75)
        
        VStack {
            TextField("Email", text: $email)
                .padding()
                .background(Color(UIColor.lightGray))
                .cornerRadius(5.0)
                .padding(.bottom, 20)
            SecureField("password", text: $password)
                .padding()
                .background(Color(UIColor.lightGray))
                .cornerRadius(5.0)
                .padding(.bottom, 20)
            Button(action: { login() }) {
                Text("Sign in")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding()
                    .frame(width: 220, height: 60)
                    .background(Color.black)
                    .cornerRadius(35.0)

            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
    

    //    Login and error message
    func login() {
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result, error) in
            if error != nil {
             self.isAlert = true
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
            } else {
                print("success")
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
struct LoginView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LoginView()
    }
}
```